# failed to install ubuntu 14.4 alonge side with windows 10

Tags: 12.04

when i try to install Ubuntu 14.4 in acer aspire e15 e5-571-37UB laptop have windows10 , during the installation of ubuntu at the time of hdd space dont show free space only show the all hdd space (500gb). Waht i can do

Comment: Can you include in your question the screenshot of the window you see?

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows Disk Manager to "shrink" the drive, say 50-100 GB. Leave it as unallocated space, then proceed with the installation again. Be sure to select this partition when installing Ubuntu and don't overwrite your Windows drive.